# Why is the wrong value being passed to my server validation function?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, webforms

On my web form I have a TextBox which I want to perform custom validation on:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="valDate" ControlToValidate="tbDate" onServerValidate="valDate_ServerValidate" ValidateEmptyText="true" ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

In my code behind, I set the date TextBox's Text in `Page_Load`, and I have a validation function:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    tbDate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString
End Sub

Protected Sub valDate_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)        
    Dim newDate As DateTime
    args.IsValid = DateTime.TryParse(args.Value, newDate)
End Sub
```

Here's the problem: If I enter a value in the textbox and click the submit button (or hit Enter), the validation function doesn't receive the value that I typed. Instead, inside `valDate_ServerValidate`, `args.Value` is set to the textbox's initial value that was set in Page_Load. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always overwriting the value, so change

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    tbDate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString
End Sub
```

to

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then tbDate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString
End Sub
```

Comment: I see. So I guess on a postback, Page_Load gets called before any validation code. Good to know.

Comment: Yes, validation and events come in a later stage in the life-cycle as Page_Load. See: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/457647/Understanding-ASP-NET-Application-and-Page-Life-Cy